# Wrapping A EF Method

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I asked a previous question where this code was provided to me:

```
public void AddRecord<T>(params T[] items) where T : class
{
    var set = Set<T>();
    foreach (var item in items)
        set.Add(item);
}
```

Now, this is great however, I would like to call this method from inside another method.  Where I can determine if I need to add or update a record.

I tried this: `public void AddNewRec(Object entity, bool add)` however an exception is thrown: `entity type Object is not part of the model for the current context`. What is going on?  What is the parameter type I should have for entity then in the wrapper method?  So confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that your `entity` parameter is of type `Object`, so when you pass it to your generic `AddRecord<T>` method, `T` becomes `Object`. Then, within that method, `Set<T>()` becomes `Set<Object>()`, and since `Object` isn't one of your entity types, your context can't find a `DbSet` for it, and it barfs.

You should be able to get it working by changing your `AddNewRec` method to a generic method instead of passing it an `Object`: try `AddNewRec<T>(T entity, bool add) where T : class`. That should allow your entity type to filter down to your `AddRecord<T>` method.